# what is meant by Unknown column in 'field list'?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This is my code in html+php. Whenever I run this page and try to input in this table of my database, a message occurs "Unknown column 'phone_outlet' in 'field list'".. What should I do? :( I can't find any error in my code? :(

This is my table in database-

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `profile_company`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile_company` (
  `profile_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `name_business_profile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `business_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `house_no` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `road_no` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `area_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `area_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `division` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `time_zone` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_office` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_outlet` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_mobile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `currency_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `currency_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `currency_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `profile_company`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my code in php+html-

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include("connection.php");

        $ProfileID=$_POST['pid'];
        $BusinessProfile=$_POST['prof'];


        $Day=$_POST['day'];
        $Month=$_POST['month'];
        $Year=$_POST['year'];


        $Nationality=$_POST['nat'];
        $BusinessID=$_POST['bid'];

        $HouseNo=$_POST['hno'];
        $RoadNo=$_POST['rno'];
        $AreaName=$_POST['area'];
        $AreaCode=$_POST['acode'];
        $District=$_POST['dis'];
        $Division=$_POST['div'];
        $Country=$_POST['country'];
        $CountryCode=$_POST['ccode'];
        $TimeZone=$_POST['time'];


        $PhoneOffice=$_POST['ophone'];
        $PhoneOutlet=$_POST['tphone'];
        $PhoneMobile=$_POST['mphone'];

        $Email1=$_POST['email1'];
        $Email2=$_POST['email2'];
        $Email3=$_POST['email3'];

        $Website1=$_POST['web1'];
        $Website2=$_POST['web2'];
        $Website3=$_POST['web3'];

        $Organization1=$_POST['org1'];
        $Organization2=$_POST['org2'];
        $Organization3=$_POST['org3'];

        $NonProfit1=$_POST['non1'];
        $NonProfit2=$_POST['non2'];
        $NonProfit3=$_POST['non3'];

        $Currency1=$_POST['curr1'];
        $Currency2=$_POST['curr2'];
        $Currency3=$_POST['curr3'];

        $SecurityCode1=$_POST['scode1'];
        $SecurityCode2=$_POST['scode2'];
        $SecurityCode3=$_POST['scode3'];


        $strFilename1=$_FILES['strFile1']['tmp_name'];
        $Photo=$_FILES['strFile1']['name'];
        $file_name1=$Photo; 






        if(is_uploaded_file($strFilename1))
            {
             if(move_uploaded_file($strFilename1,"UserCompany/$file_name1"))
                {
                    $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO profile_individual(profile_id,name_business_profile,day,month,year,nationality,
                                                                        business_id,house_no,road_no,area_name,area_code,district,division,
                                                                        country,country_code,time_zone,phone_office,phone_outlet,phone_mobile,other_email_1,
                                                                        other_email_2,other_email_3,website_1,website_2,website_3,organization_1,
                                                                        organization_2,organization_3,nonprofit_1,nonprofit_2,nonprofit_3,currency_1,currency_2,
                                                                        currency_3,security_code_1,security_code_2,security_code_3,logo)
                    VALUES('$ProfileID','$BusinessProfile','$Day','$Month','$Year','$Nationality','$BusinessID',
                           '$HouseNo','$RoadNo','$AreaName','$AreaCode','$District','$Division','$Country','$CountryCode','$TimeZone','$PhoneOffice',
                           '$PhoneOutlet','$PhoneMobile','$Email1','$Email2','$Email3','$Website1','$Website2','$Website3','$Organization1',
                           '$Organization2','$Organization3','$NonProfit1','$NonProfit2','$NonProfit3','$Currency1','$Currency2','$Currency3',
                           '$SecurityCode1','$SecurityCode2','$SecurityCode3','$Photo')");

                    if($result)
                    {
                        header("Location: home.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Failed!";
                    } 

                }  
            }

            echo mysql_error();

}
?>



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>



<style type="text/css">

</style>


<h1>  <center> Edit Your Business Profile </center> </h1>

</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> *Profile ID [Anything Unique]: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="pid" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> *Business Profile Name: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="prof" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 



    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> *Basic Information </b></td>
    </tr> 



    <tr>
            <td> <b> Date of Establishment: </b> </td> 
            <td> <select name="day" aria-label="Day"> 
            <option value="-1">Day:</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select> <!--/td>

        <td--> <select name="month" aria-label="Month">
            <option value="-1">Month:</option>
            <option value="1">Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
            <option value="4">Apr</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">Jun</option>
            <option value="7">Jul</option>
            <option value="8">Aug</option>
            <option value="9">Sep</option>
            <option value="10">Oct</option>
            <option value="11">Nov</option>
            <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select> <!--/td>

<td--> 
<select name="year" aria-label="Year">
<option value="-1">Year:</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1914">1914</option>
<option value="1913">1913</option>
<option value="1912">1912</option>
<option value="1911">1911</option>
<option value="1910">1910</option>
<option value="1909">1909</option>
<option value="1908">1908</option>
<option value="1907">1907</option>
<option value="1906">1906</option>
<option value="1905">1905</option>
<option value="1905">1904</option>
<option value="1905">1903</option>
<option value="1905">1902</option>
<option value="1905">1901</option>
<option value="1905">1900</option>
</select>
</td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td> <b> Nationality: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="nat" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 


    <tr>
        <td> <b> Business ID: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="bid" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 


    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> *Addresses </b></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> House No.: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="hno" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Road No.: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="rno" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Area Name: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="area" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Area Code: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="acode" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> District: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="dis" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Division: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="div" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Country: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="country" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Country Code: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="ccode" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Time Zone: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="time" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr> 


    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> *Contact Numbers </b> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Office: </b> </td>
        <td> <input type="number" name="ophone" placeholder=""> </td> 
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Outlet: </b> </td>
        <td> <input type="number" name="tphone" placeholder=""> </td> 
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Mobile: </b> </td>
        <td> <input type="number" name="mphone" placeholder=""> </td> 
    </tr> 


    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> Other Email Address [If Any] </b> </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Email Address: </b> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="email1" placeholder=""> </td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Email Address: </b> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="email2" placeholder=""> </td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Email Address: </b> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="email3" placeholder=""> </td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> Other Websites [If Any] </b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Website: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="web1" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Website: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="web2" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Website: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="web3" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> Other Organizations [If Any] </b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Organization: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="org1" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Organization: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="org2" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Organization: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="org3" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>   


    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> Non-profit Businesses [If Any] </b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Business Name: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="non1" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Business Name: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="non2" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Business Name: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="non3" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> Preferred Currencies </b></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Currency: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="curr1" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Currency: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="curr2" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Currency: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="curr3" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b> *Security Codes </b></td>
        <td>  [Must be Remembered] </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Security Code 1: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="number" name="scode1" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Security Code 2: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="number" name="scode2" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Security Code 3: </b></td>
        <td> <input type="number" name="scode3" placeholder=""/> </td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td> <b> __________________________ </b> </td>
        <td> <b> __________________ </b> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <b> Upload Image: </b> </td> 
        <td> <input type="file" name="strFile1" id="strFile1" /> </td> 
    </tr> 



    <tr>    
            <td> </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"> </td>
    </tr>



    </table>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you have to dump *all* of your code here?

Comment: @JohnConde - and yet not enough. The table description is for profile_company. The INSERT is going in to profile_individual.

Comment: insert into profile_individual and create table profile_company? not same table?

Comment: What is the structure for table profile_individual?  You are showing the table structure for profile_company.  It looks like profile_individual does not have a field called `phone_outlet`.

Answer (score 5):

you are inserting into the wrong table. you have column `phone_outlet` in table profile_company  but you are inserting in table profile_individual

Comment: Unlikely. If `profile_individual` didn't exist, the error would be `1146: Table 'profile_individual' doesn't exist`.

Comment: Actually there's a table named profile_individual. @PhpMyCoder 

Let me know why the error is showing only for phone_outlet column?

Answer (score 0):

This error message is caused when a column name which you specify in an `INSERT` statement's field list does not exist in the table into which you are inserting data.

The field list is the part of the `INSERT` statement where you specify the order of the fields you are providing in the query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(column1, column2, column3) VALUES('data 1', 'data 2', 'data 3');
                      ^ this is the field list ^
```

Likely this is caused by a mistyping of one of the column names, but we can't know for sure unless you provide the full error message

Say, for example you had a table called Person:

```
Person
-----------
first_name VARCHAR(255)
last_name  VARCHAR(255)
```

With this table, if you attempted the following SQL you would get `Unknown column in field list 'frist_name'` (Notice the typo):

```
INSERT INTO Person(frist_name, last_name) VALUES('Jeff', 'Atwood');
                   ^ This field doesn't exist in Person, but fIRst_name does!
```

You also are inserting into `profile_individual`, but you didn't include it's schema. I assume it has one since you're not getting a table does not exists, but without its schema you can't tell which column is typed incorrectly in the field list.

You can get a more concise representation of `profile_individual` by executing:

```
EXPLAIN profile_individual;
```

---

**EDIT:** As you mention this error references a column named `phone_outlet`. This means that `phone_outlet` is not a column in `profile_individual`. If you need to add this column, execute:

ALTER TABLE profile_individual ADD phone_outlet VARCHAR(255);

(Just substitue the proper datatype in place of `VARCHAR(255)`)

However, I notice that your code is currently using the **deprecated** `mysql_*` family of functions and is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You can get two birds with one stone if you switch to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Also, I notice a pattern in your column names: `some_value_1`, `some_value_2`, etc. What if there are more than the number of columns which you provide. For example, what if an individual has more than 3 emails. A better schema for this is to abstract the idea of an email to a new table. That means, creating an `emails` table which has a column for the email address and another (called a foreign key), which links the email to the individual.

For more on this, check out [Database Relationships 101 on Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/).

Comment: No worries! Now you know what a field list is. Also, I made some suggestions for the curent schema and the methods from which you are accessing MySQL for you to read. Also, at SO we show thanks with +1's and green check marks :P

Comment: I'm so sorry. This site wants something like reputation for green check mark... :( I have only 1 reputation as I joined this site just today. :( and thank you once again for all of your helps. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're inserting into the wrong table.

The table you created is `profile_company`, but your `INSERT` is on `profile_individual`.

Comment: Unlikely. If `profile_individual` didn't exist, the error would be `1146: Table 'profile_individual' doesn't exist`.

Comment: I didn't meant it doesn't exists.